# POI hyperlink is truncated

Tags: java, excel, hyperlink, apache-poi

I'm trying to get the URL from a Hyperlink in an Excel cell. I am finding that it is usually truncated, and not the complete URL.  When I open the spreadsheet in LibreOffice, I can see the full URL.

```
Cell c = r.getCell(n);
Hyperlink link = c.getHyperlink();
String address = link.getAddress();
System.out.println(address); // truncated!
```

For example, in the spreadsheet, I see "http://www.co.brown.wi.us/i/f/NewsletterWinter 2012(1).pdf";  When I use the code above, it prints out "http://www.co.brown.wi.us/i/f/NewsletterWinter%20".

This is happening in pretty much every hyperlink in the spreadsheet.

How do you get the non-truncated URL?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Are you sure, the hyperlink is working in the spreadsheet? I suspect even in the spreadsheet only `http://www.co.brown.wi.us/i/f/NewsletterWinter` is linked like it is also in your question. The `2012(1).pdf` then is only unlinked cell content.

Comment: The odd thing there is it's not split at the spaces - it's actually replacing those with "%20" like it should.

If I open the spreadsheet in Excel 2013 or LibreOffice 4.3, the links work.  If I parse them with Poi 3.12 / JDK 8, it truncates the URL.

Comment: As I said, I can't reproduce this behavior. Can you upload the spreadsheet somewhere?